# Составление сложного запроса

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla, запрос

Есть таблица:

[image: Таблица1]

Возможно ли составить запрос такого вида:
Записи группируются по `id_test`, для каждого такого выводятся данные из таблицы `guest` если `id_guest != -1` иначе если `id_user == -1` просто вывести запись. 
Подобным образом вывести записи где есть `id_user != -1`, но здесь необходимо сгруппировать по внутреннему атрибуту `id_group` таблицы `user`.

Думаю если использовать хранимые процедуры, то это возможно реализовать, но я создаю проект на joomla, поэтому необходимо избежать процедуры.

Если вопрос не понятен, оставляйте комментарий, поправлю.

Comment: Так у вас все таки 2 таблицы, данная (кстати, как она называется) и guest (кстати, что в ней). На вскидку скажу, что надо gust присоединить по `left join guest on guest.id=Table.id_guest and Table.id_guest!=-1` (хотя -1 для обозначения отсутствия - это плохой выбор, для таких случаев специально предусмотрено значение NULL). В списке выборки там где поля есть в обоих таблицах и надо взять или из одной или из другой, скорее всего будет достаточно `coalesce(guest.X, Table.X)` если по цепляемой таблице надо группировать, то надо внимательнее на нее посмотреть, может union какой сделать

Comment: И да, если в группировке предполагается еще поле из дркгой таблицы _вместо_ id_test, то значит надо сделать так что бы в нужных записях это поле оказывалось на месте id_test и группировать по признаку из какой таблицы запись и этому полю

Comment: Вообще три таблицы: `answer`, в ней  `id_test` `id_guest` `id_user` и еще некоторые поля, таблица `guest` и таблица users.
Вообще это можно сделать с помощью двух запросов, но мне интересно возможно ли с помощью одного. Все это делается для получения результата вида:

`-id_test
--guest
---id_guest (и так далее)
--user
---group1
----id_user
---group2
----id_user`

Comment: С помощью одного запроса можно, вообще все, что угодно. Надо только описать задачу более продробно. указав структуру всех таблиц, пример данных в них, и главное, что на основе этих данных ожидается получить на выходе